# How to add header,username,password sharepoint webservice using ksoap in android

Tags: android, web-services, sharepoint, xmlpullparser

I am writing an Android application that will use the getlistitems() method of the lists.amx service in sharepoint 2010. I am using ksoap2-android to handle my soap messages. When I try to authenticate I get an xmlpullparser exception expected START_TAG... Why will the following code not authenticate to the sharepoint server?

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetListItems";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.domain.com/tr-TR/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tve);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


    request.addProperty("listName", "Haberler");
    request.addProperty("viewName", null);
    request.addProperty("query", null);
    request.addProperty("viewFields", null);
    request.addProperty("rowLimit", "30");
    request.addProperty("queryOptions", null);
    request.addProperty("webID",null);




    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

//      envelope.headerOut=new Element[1];
//      envelope.headerOut[0]=buildAuthHeader();

```
    String authentication = android.util.Base64.encodeToString("myusername:mypassword".getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
    List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    headers.add(new HeaderProperty("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED","f" +authentication));

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope,headers);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        tv.setText(response.toString());
        Log.e("SONUC",response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual SOAP message that is getting sent to SharePoint?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>string</listName>
      <viewName>string</viewName>
      <query>string</query>
      <viewFields>string</viewFields>
      <rowLimit>string</rowLimit>
      <queryOptions>string</queryOptions>
      <webID>string</webID>
    </GetListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

Don't send null values. Instead, add all the values and then try sending it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `NtlmTransport` instead of `HttpTransportSE`. MayBe it works for you.